# Bootstrap 3 and CodeIgniter 3 Google Maps API v3 BIOSTALL Library show a gray square

Tags: html, codeigniter, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was using pure html and css on my views and works perfectly fine but i changed only the views and began to use bootstrap 3, now the div with the map just show a grey square,my view:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            Map                             
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php echo $map['html'];?> 
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

What can i do to make it show?

Comment: Hi. Author of the CI library here. There are two reasons I can think this might happen: 1) You're passing it an invalid address/co-ordinates or 2) When the window loads the map is hidden from view in a tab, accordian or  similar. Either of these sound feasible?

Comment: Hi @BIOSTALL , thanks for you answer, i think it's a problem with bootstrap, because i make a test without bootstrap and you library work perfectly, check twice for your options and none of these are feasible.

Comment: @BIOSTALL I just fix my map, but it's a little bit confusing, i have to put: `<?php echo $map['html'];?>`  `<?php echo $map['js']; ?>`  to make it work, and show just one map.